# three.js / why does text texture look so miserable?

Tags: text, three.js, textures

trying to apply a texture to an 3D- text I wonder why it looks so....ungood. 
The texture is only applied to the letters faces and the sides only show stripes. Obviously I am doing something wrong or there is a better way to do it. For both cases I would appreciate help.

Thanks in advance.

I tried the code you see.
Then I tried something similar like here:

https://www.script-tutorials.com/webgl-with-three-js-lesson-4/
under 3D text which resulted in a textured surface and just colored sides which may have to do with the MeshFaceMaterial is deprecated as stated here:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/deprecated/DeprecatedList
under Materials.

```
    var size    =   0.251;
    var height  =   0.125;
    var loader  =   new THREE.FontLoader();

        loader.load( './Arial_Regular.json'

    ,   function ( font ) {

            letters = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'tHIS is AN Example',  {
                                                                        font            :   font,
                                                                        size            :   size,
                                                                        height          :   height,
                                                                        curveSegments   :   2,
                                                                        bevelEnabled    :   true,
                                                                        bevelThickness  :   0.02,
                                                                        bevelSize       :   0.05,

                                                                        bevelSegments   :   2


                                                                     }
            );

            letters             .   center();

        var texture             =   new THREE.TextureLoader().load('wildtextures-brushed-metal-shets.jpg');
            texture.wrapS       =   texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.repeat      .   set                                     (   1
                                                                            ,   1
                                                                            );
            texture.needsUpdate =   true;
            texture.anisotropy  =   16;





        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
```

THREE.TextureLoader().load('wildtextures_rust-signs-on-the-blue-metal-sheet.jpg');

```
            that.letter_mesh            =   new THREE.Mesh                  (   letters
                                                                            ,   material
                                                                            );
            that.scene                  .   add                             (   that.letter_mesh    )
```

I would like the texture to smoothly apply to the text faces and the sides.

[image: example picture]

```
Meanwhile I tried using a shader doing the job:

THREE.ShaderLib['custom'] = {

    vertexShader: [

        "varying vec2 vUv;",
        "void main() {",
            "vUv            =   uv;",
            "gl_PointSize   =   8.0;",
            "gl_Position    =   projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);",
        "}",
    ].join("\n"),

    fragmentShader: [

        "varying vec2 vUv;",
        "uniform sampler2D texture;",
        "void main() {",
        "gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vUv);",
        "}",
    ].join("\n")
};
var Shader      =   THREE.ShaderLib             [ "custom" ];
var uniforms    =   THREE.UniformsUtils.clone   ( Shader.uniforms );

var _material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

    fragmentShader  :   Shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader    :   Shader.vertexShader,

    uniforms        : {

        texture: (  {   type    :   "t"
                    ,   value   :   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("wildtextures-brushed-metal-shets.jpg") } ) 
    }

});


And it looks similar to the former result so this did not work out either.
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I quickly reviewed your code and everything you're trying to do seems reasonable.  However, your output is still bad...

I did some digging and I found a relevant answer to your problem.  This link contains an example of a nicely applied texture, but also an explanation of why textures cannot always be nicely applied.

**Relevant Link:**

[Texturing 3D-Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807184/three-js-rendering-3d-text-with-custom-texture)

**Good 3D-Texturing Ex:**

[Good Texturing 3D-Text](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Text3D-Textures.html)

**Excerpt:**

> TextGeometry doesn't provide UV coordinates and if you think a bit it would be really hard to abstract that process and serialize it for any text geometry. Text is yet another form of custom mesh, therefore, you would have to provide textureCoord attribute manually and use ShaderMaterial to sample textures. Hope this helps.

I hope this gets you in the right direction.

**Update:**

I think you need to create a second material and apply it to the mesh like this:

```
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [ material1, material2 ] );
```

That is supposed to replace the behavior of MeshFaceMaterial.  I'll try to get you a more concrete answer tomorrow.

Comment: Hello Matthew, thank you for your time. I stumbled over these links, too, before and I could not get it right. In the link from Stemkoski I saw the usage of the MeshFaceMaterial which I tried until I read that it is deprecated. I might should have mentioned that I am using THREE.js R106.

Comment: Is your primary objective to get some nice texture wrapping on 3D-text (like Stemkoski's)?  If you don't need the features of R106, maybe consider using R60 which doesn't have a deprecated MeshFaceMaterial.

Comment: Hey Matthew, thanks again. I considered using an older versin of three.js but somehow I would like to use the "most modern available". I will keep that in mind as a "last resort".

Comment: I tried the 2-materials-thing and it looks the same. I tried ( texture )material, ( texture )material  and ( texture )material, ( shader)material  and vice versa. It all gets the same result.